# Look for part of a string in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string-search

i'm looking for an efficient way to look for certain words, would i use switch/case, int/string.IndexOf('!'); foreach loop/contains?

i have a string that i'm receiving from a client.  so, let's say i get:

```
string x = "fjdswordslkjf?dkHEYw";
```

i have an array of possible values that correspond with that message.
(none of this is syntactically correct, just so you get an idea):

```
someArray[0]= "?";
someArray[1]= "HEY";
someArray[2]= "find.me";
```

basically i want to know

```
 if (x contains someWordinSomeArray)
```

i want to search through the string x, using the words in the array.  what would be the most efficient way to do this in c#?  i just need a bool response, not the exact location in the string.

ANSWER

here's what i used:

```
foreach (string searchstring in valuesArray)
        {
            indx = test.IndexOf(searchstring);
            if (indx > -1)
            {
                testValue = true;
                break;
            }             
        }
```

Comment: Would you class `find.me` as one word or two?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to know whether *any* of the words in `someArray` are in `x`, or whether *each* of the words in `someArray` are in `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array, and exit as soon as you find a match:

```
bool found = someArray.Any(s => x.Contains(s));
```

A non-LINQ version of the same would be:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (string s in someArray) {
  if (x.Contains(s)) {
    found = true;
    break; // exit from loop
  }
}
```

Comment: @thermacore: That is the string that you get from the client, as per your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriate extension method depending on exactly you want. Suppose that the input string is stored in `s`, and that the array of words you want to check is `wordsToMatch`. Then:

... if you want to know whether *any* of the words match:

```
var stringMatched = wordsToMatch.Any(w => s.Contains(w));
// true or false
```

... if you want to know *which* words match:

```
var matchingWords = wordsToMatch.Where(w => s.Contains(w));
// ["apple", "ban", "banana", "nana", "coconut", "nut", ...]
```

... if you want to know whether *each* word matches:

```
var wordMatchResult = wordsToMatch.Select(w => s.Contains(w));
// [true, true, false, true, false, true, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework has a string.contains method that does what you want to do. Loop through the array. For each item in the array, check if x.Contains(item) is true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

```
string s1 = "fjdswordslkjf?dkHEYw";
foreach (String s in array)
    b = s1.Contains(Array[item]);  //will be T or F
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool CheckForString(string[] someArray,string x)
    {          
      foreach(string s in someArray)
        if(x.contains(s))
          return true;
      return false;
    }
```

I think "contains" is faster than indexOf()